# Java EE 7 Security not redirecting users to the login page

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am having trouble getting unauthenticated users to be forced to login before viewing the web app.

The setup is Java ee 7, Glassfish 4.0 and the IDE is Netbeans 8.0

I am using form based security and a JDBCRealm.

My XML setup is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-role>
    <description>Trader User</description>
    <role-name>trader</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>AdminUser</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>AdminAccess</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AllAdminOperations</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>     
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Admin Only Access</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>JDBCAuth</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

And the sun-web.xml has the following mappings:

```
<class-loader delegate="true"/>
<jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
        <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
</jsp-config>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>trader</role-name>
    <group-name>trader</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

As the URL pattern is set to:
    /*

I thought that this would make all users trying to access the app be redirect to the login page?

The users and groups are setup in the DB and mapped to glassfish JDBCAuth realm ok. I can navigate to the login form enter a users details, login, and there will be no security errors;  if I enter incorrect details I will be directed to the loginError.xhtml page as expected.

The part I do not understand is why when the project is deployed unauthenticated can freely access all web pages?

Note -- netbeans 8.0 generated a sun-web.xml for the glassfish descriptor file.  I understand this is deprecated but should be compatible.

I cant seem to figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE -- GAS log file:

INFO:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
INFO:   JMS010: ADDRESSLIST in setJmsServiceProvider: mq://localhost:7676/
INFO:   JMS08: JMS Service Connection URL is : mq://localhost:7676/
INFO:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7,676]
INFO:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.0  (Build 14-e) Compile:  April 12 2013 0104
INFO:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is EMBEDDED, connection mode is Direct
INFO:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB PriceREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.PriceREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TradeCreator: [java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeCreator!org.ProjectProto2.TradingEngine.TradeCreator, java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeCreator]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TradeREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.TradeREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB PriceEJB: [java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceEJB!org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB, java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceEJB]
INFO:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB PriceEJB: [org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB, org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB#org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB OrderEJB: [java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderEJB, java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderEJB!org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB]
INFO:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB OrderEJB: [org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB, org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB#org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB OrderREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.OrderREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)
WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled

INFO:   Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.ProjectProto2.Rest.ConfigREST, at the servlet mapping /resources/*, with the Application class of the same name.
INFO:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/ProjectProto2'
INFO:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
INFO:   Loading application [ProjectProto2] at [/ProjectProto2]
INFO:   Loading application ProjectProto2 done in 21,159 ms
INFO:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (5,058ms), startup services(26,039ms), total(31,097ms)
INFO:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
INFO:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://joseph-K56CA:8686/jndi/rmi://joseph-K56CA:8686/jmxrmi
INFO:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
INFO:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
INFO:   visiting unvisited references

INFO:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
INFO:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 102ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 ) for context ''
INFO:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@176fda35 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@10e9bd6f.
INFO:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
INFO:   Loading application __admingui done in 5,439 ms
INFO:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
INFO:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 78ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]

WARNING:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /home/joseph/NetBeansProjects/mscproject/ProjectProto2/target/ProjectProto2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
INFO:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
INFO:   file:/home/joseph/NetBeansProjects/mscproject/ProjectProto2/target/ProjectProto2-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/_mscprojectv1_ProjectProto2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU login successful
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB PriceEJB: [java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceEJB!org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB, java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceEJB]
INFO:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB PriceEJB: [org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB, org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB#org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IPriceEJB]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TradeREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.TradeREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB OrderEJB: [java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderEJB, java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderEJB!org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB]
INFO:   EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB OrderEJB: [org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB, org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB#org.ProjectProto2.EJB.IOrderEJB]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB OandaPriceHandlerV2: [java:global/ProjectProto2/OandaPriceHandlerV2, java:global/ProjectProto2/OandaPriceHandlerV2!org.ProjectProto2.PriceHandlers.OandaPriceHandlerV2]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.SingletonBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TradeCreator: [java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeCreator!org.ProjectProto2.TradingEngine.TradeCreator, java:global/ProjectProto2/TradeCreator]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB PriceREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.PriceREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/PriceREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB OrderREST: [java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderREST, java:global/ProjectProto2/OrderREST!org.ProjectProto2.Rest.OrderREST]
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: com.sun.ejb.monitoring.stats.StatelessSessionBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
WARNING:   Flashlight listener registration failed for listener class: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.monitoring.stats.MessageDrivenBeanStatsProvider , will retry later
INFO:   Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.ProjectProto2.Rest.ConfigREST, at the servlet mapping /resources/*, with the Application class of the same name.
INFO:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 ) for context '/ProjectProto2'
INFO:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
INFO:   Loading application [ProjectProto2] at [/ProjectProto2]
INFO:   ProjectProto2 was successfully deployed in 14,532 milliseconds

Comment: just curious would the problem remain if you change sun-web.xml to glassfish-web.xml? I have never faced this kind of problem.

Comment: Hi jjd  -- Thanks for your comment.  I have changed the xml to glassfish-web.xml but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Took your config files, altered them to be able to use in my environment(just role names and mappings), works perfectly as it should. I would suggest you to download a clean GAS instance and configure it from scratch. Must be something wrong with the config

Comment: BTW what URL do you use to access you protected resources(just in case)?

Comment: @jjd -- Thanks for taking a look on your local environment.  I download a new GAS but still no luck.  To double check that any type of authentication works I ran the tut-install/examples/security/hello1-formauth/  example and this also did not ask me to login?  Thinking this was odd I ran the same tutorial in wildfly 8.1 and I was asked to log in as expected.  I think I will bite the bullet and migrate over to wildfly.

Comment: Could you provide the URL for your protected resource from which a not authorized request is not redirected to the login page (I mean for the config files you put in your question here)?  Also it would be nice to know your GAS version.

Comment: and if you are still interested in finding the source of the problem, what you have in your  AS log file?

Comment: @jjd definitely still interested in finding out why.  The main pages are in the UI folder, for example:  http://localhost:8080/ProjectProto2/faces/UI/tradeDisplay.xhtml.  The version is Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89).  AS log file in question update.

Comment: another question is the project structure on your file system. Basically I faces different kinds of strange behavior, like redirecting to a some strange address that ends with  javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo instead of a requested protected page(this happens when I use url-pattern from your config for the JSF servlet), but never was able to reproduce the error you mentioned.